# android - include layout or fragment

Tags: java, android, layout, include, fragment

Let's say that I have a class TitleBar which calls `title_bar.xml` layout file. Some TextViews are set in `TitleBar.java` file so `title_bar.xml` is dependent to it. What is the easiest way to include this layout file? Obviously, using just `include layout` won't do the job. Should I use fragments in this case? I'd prefer using `include` but I just don't know how to call code-behind file too?

Hope that my question was clear enough.

Thanks

**EDIT:** 
Currently, TitleBar is an activity. Should I change that to something else?

**EDIT 2:**
Let me try to ask in different way: I have MainActivity and activity_main.xml files. How can I include in activity_main.xml new layout file (title_bar.xml) and relate TitleBar.java class to this new view? How should TitleBar.java look like? Should I create it as an activity too?

Answer (score 0):

You need only layout file or the TitleBar functionality?
Why not use `<path.to.your.TitleBar/>` in layout? Would be logical to extend TitleBar from View.

Other option include placing an empty container in place where you wan your title bar (where you wanted to do include). For example `<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/toolbarWillBeHere"` and when the right time comes (in your activity onCreate, for example) just find that container and put your toolbar inside

Comment: I need both. This is re-usable layout

Comment: I edited my question: Currently, TitleBar is an activity. Should I change that to something else?

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is here: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html

Basically you add your view/layout in xml using something like:

```
<com.your.package.name.TitleBar
  id="@+id/titleBar"
  ... />
```

Answer (score -1):

By just `including the layout` will do the job.

Once your layout is attached to your `layout xml file`, it becomes part of your layout file, and then you can use `findViewByID` to get the object of your desired `View.`

Comment: Yes but then all the code I have in TitleBar has to be copy/pasted in Activity that calls this layout